# TDirectory.GetFiles() is not working in Delphi 11

Tags: android, delphi, permissions, delphi-11-alexandria

In Delphi 10.4, I was able to get a listing of files in an Android  device's shared storage. In Delphi 11, with necessary permission set (either programmatically or on the device), `TDirectory.GetFiles()` is returning an empty list (ie. zero entries).

`TDirectory.GetDirectories()` is working correctly, and using `TFile.Exists()` with a filename which I know to be present returns true. But, if I try to open that file with, for instance, `TFile.ReadAllText()`, access is denied. Any suggestions?

This is an example program which fails in Delphi 11:

```pascal
uses
  System.Types,System.Classes,system.sysUtils,system.IOUtils,system.Permissions,
 {$IFDEF ANDROID}
   Androidapi.Helpers,
   Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
   Androidapi.JNI.Os,
 {$ENDIF}
  FMX.Types,FMX.Forms,FMX.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
   procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
   fOK:boolean;
   procedure PermissionsResult(Sender: TObject;
      const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray;
      const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.fmx}

procedure Tform1.PermissionsResult(Sender: TObject;
  const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray;
  const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray);
 var
  n:integer;
 begin
  if length(AGrantResults)>0 then
   for n:=0 to length(AGrantResults)-1 do
    if not (AGrantResults[n] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then fOK:=false;
 end;

procedure FileList(dir:string;list:TstringList);
 var
  LList: TStringDynArray;
  I: Integer;
 begin
  list.Clear;
  Llist:=Tdirectory.GetFiles(dir);
  if length(LList)>0 then
   for I := 0 to Length(LList) - 1 do
    list.Add(LList[I]);
 end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 var
  DataDir:string;
  list:TstringList;
  p:Tarray<string>;
 begin
  fOK:=true;
  p:=[JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
        JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)];
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions(p,PermissionsResult,nil);
  if fOK then
   begin
    list:=TstringList.Create;
    DataDir := TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath;
showmessage(DataDir);
    fileList(DataDir,list);
showmessage(inttostr(list.Count)+' '+list.Text);
    list.Free;
   end else showmessage('permission refused');
 end;

end.
```

Comment: Which Android API targets are specified in the two versions?

Comment: I should have said, for Delphi 10.4 it is 29, for Delphi 11 it is 32

Answer (score 1):

On an Android 11+ devices listFiles() will, depending on the exact public directory, list only files created by the app itself or some media files.

Do not only use TFile.Exists() but also TFile.CanRead() before you try to .. read.

Comment: But surely the point of a "sharedDocumentsPath" is that files can be shared between apps? Also, this does not explain why on the same Android 11 device Tdirectory.getFiles works on Delphi 10.4 but not on Delphi 11.2?

Comment: It is not the used function but the used path. So better become specific.

Comment: The used path, as shown in the code above, is TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, or am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Documents

Comment: which is always the path for getSharedDocumentsPath as given in the Embarcadero documentation: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath

Comment: The full path is: /storage/emulated/0/Documents

Comment: Is it the same for all Delphi versions?

Comment: But to make it short. The shared documents path naming is out of time. It will not work to share files between apps on Android 11+ devices for the reason i started my answer with. Instead you can use a (File)Provider with one app which serves files to other apps. An app can get access to all files if tou implement the settings intent needed for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet that demonstrates this, or point to Embarcadero documentation which illustrates this?

Comment: I do not program with Delphi and Google can tell you this i hope.

Comment: The difference in these Delphi versions is what compatibility they request from Android. That's controlled by the TargetAPILevel in the Android manifest all apps need to have (the manifest XML file the IDE put into your source directory). Issue is: if one wants to support newer Android versions or needs to publish the app on Google Play one needs to adapt to the compatibility requirements Google places on such newer Android versions and they made changes to file storage in shared folders :-( Which makes some things more complex or not doable at all anymore...

Answer (score -1):

This will list files:

```
var
  FileList: TStringDynArray;
  myfileList: Tstringlist;
  s: string;
  DocDir: string; 
begin
  DocDir := TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath;// or whatever path
  FileList := TDirectory.GetFiles(DocDir);
  myfileList := TStringList.Create;

  for s in FileList do begin //get all items in folder
    if Pos('.png',s) > 0 then begin
      try  
        myfileList.Add(s);             
      except
        //
      end;  
    end;
  end;
  myfileList.Free;  
end;
```

Comment: But, for me at least, it does not on Delphi 11 on Android.

Comment: On a side note: `GetFiles()` has a `SearchPattern` property: `TDirectory.GetFiles(DocDir, '*.png')` so you don't need the `Pos()` check